# How can I find the background image of a clicked element (or the nearest child or parent element that has a background image) using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a Chrome extension that I want to use to provide the user with the URL of a background image using Chrome's right-click context menu.

Right now my problem is finding the background image. If a user right-clicks the correct element then it's easy. **But if they click a child of that element then I have to look at the parents. What's the most efficient way to handle this?**

Some notes: I'm not injecting jQuery with my extension. And I've also thought of the scenario where an element that is absolutely positioned above the desired background image would get in the way. But I'm not concerned with that at the moment.

Here is my code so far. It works as long as the clicked element has a `background-image`. Failing to find one, it does not look at the parents yet.

```
document.body.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev) {

    // get computed style
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(ev.target, false);

    // img src is inside 'url(' + ')' - slice those off
    var src = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1);

    console.log(src);

    return false;
}, false);
```

Comment: Well, the image could be in either the selected item, or any item from that node up to the root.  So you would just walk that queue up higher and higher until you find the image.  Worst case, N items iterated to find the background image, where N is the node count from click to root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function getBackgroundImage(el) {
    if (el == null) {
      return null;
    }
    var backgroundImage = window.getComputedStyle(el, false).getPropertyValue("background-image");
    if (backgroundImage !== 'none') {
      return backgroundImage.slice(4, -1);
    } else {
      return getBackgroundImage(el.parentElement);
    }
}

document.body.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev) {
    var src = getBackgroundImage(ev.target);
    console.log(src);
}, false);
```

```css
.grand-child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.parent {
  background: url('http://google.com');
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to use computed styles because it seems like without it, your code does not work with elements using the `background` attribute as opposed to CSS. I've tried to implement it but I don't get any values after the first loop.